# No logro hacer que este método GET por nombre funcione

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs

```
   //Método para traer los estudiantes por Nombre
    //Ejemplo: GET http://localhost:8080/items?filter=ABC
    router.get('/estudiante/name',(req,res,next)=>{
        var sql = require("mssql");

        //var FirstName = req.params.FirstName;

        // config for your database
          var config = {
                user: 'martin',
                password: '1234',
                server: 'JMTABORDA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS', 
                database: 'school' 
            };


        sql.connect(config, function (err) {

            if (err) console.log(err);

            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();

            // query to the database and get the records
            request.query('select * from Student WHERE FirstName=' +FirstName, function (err, recordset) {

                if (err) console.log(err)

                // send records as a response
                res.send(recordset);
                res.end();

            });


        });



    });
```

Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal, cual es la forma correcta para pasar el nombre y que me lo traiga de la base de datos

Comment: Aparece algún error o será que la consulta no trae datos? Pareciera que faltaran las comillas antes y después del nombre

Comment: Muchas Gracias Klaimmore, efectivamente si era por las comillas que faltaban.

Answer (score 0):

ya logre que me funcionará, haciéndolo de la siguiente manera:

```
   // query to the database and get the records
            request.query("select * from Student  WHERE FirstName = '"+FirstName+"'", function (err, recordset) {

                if (err) console.log(err)

                // send records as a response
                res.send(recordset);


            });
```

De esta forma lo logro traer por una consulta implementando un WHERE, por ejemplo diciendole en la URL 
http://localhost:3000/estudiante/name?FirstName=MARIA

Ahora me queda  una duda, si yo quisiera traer una consulta implementando un LIKE como sería bajo esta misma lógica. Por ejemplo para traer todos los estudiantes que empiecen por la letra M.

En SQL lo traigo así:

SELECT *

FROM [school].[dbo].[Student]
  WHERE FirstName like 'M%'

Pero como llevo esa logica a Node JS, asi como lo hice con el Where.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Como paso esa logica del LIKE Aca: request.query("select * from Student  WHERE FirstName = '"+FirstName+"'", function (err, recordset)